Analysis Server Locked Symbol
we have a SSIS project running on a remote server. We have set up a SourceTree - Bitbucket system where everyone can edit this project on their own machine and synchronise it to the remote machine.
When I took the project to my own machine and ran it on Visual Studio, I saw a lock sign next to the AS server. How can I solve this problem, what is the reason for this?
enter image description here
I thought that my domain user does not have authorisation on AS, but I have access authorisation for AS.
